# How to dismissed dialog after navigate other screen flutter..?

Tags: flutter, dialog

suppose i have a button named is A. so when i press A , a popup dialog is appear and inside dialog , there is also a button named Next. so i'll be navigate by pressing Next.
BUT the problem is when i came back previous screen the Dialog is also appear.
so how can i dismissed the dialog after navigate and can't appear if i return.

I've try this way, it work but appear some miliseconds...

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteNames.variantScreen,
                      arguments: product.id.toString())
                  .whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop(true))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the dialog first and then navigate to new route

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop(); //close the dialog
Navigator.pushNamed(.... //goto new route
```